# PHP How to get an Array from an Array where the keys have equal Values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm searching for a method like `array_column` that, returns an array, from a column input array where the given key is the same.
sth. like this:

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 123,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4321,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 123,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1234,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    )
);

getFromArray($records, 'first_name', 'id'); //getFromArray(Array $input, mixed $value, mixed $key)
/* should retrun
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Jane
)
*/
```

Thanks for every usefull help ^^

Comment: Should `'key'` be `123`?

Comment: Do it in two steps. First user `array_filter()` to get the elements with that key, then use `array_column()` to get the names.

Comment: There's no built-in function that does this, you'll have to write it yourself.

Comment: And what if there're two keys `123` and two keys `1234`?

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I'll try it ;)

Comment: @u_mulder 123 != 1234 so it only returns 123 like in the example.

Comment: Then fix your question - you need items not __with same keys__ but with keys equal to some provided value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might help you on your way:

First - use `array_filter()` to find records with `id`'s equal to '123':

```
$needle = '123';
$result = array_filter($records, function ($v) use ($needle) {
        return $v['id'] == $needle; // when TRUE store value into result array
});
```

Second - use `array_colum()` on the result to get `first_name`'s of hits:

```
$column = 'first_name';
$result = array_column($result, $column);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "John"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Jane"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getFromArray($arrays, $key, $value) {
   foreach($arrays as $array) {
      foreach($array as $k => $v) {
         if ($k == $key && $v == $value) {
            return $array;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you compared the output of your function with the required output the OP is looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are querying a database to get your ids, first names and last names. In that case, if your db is based on postgresql, then do this :

```php
$records = pg_query($query); // this returns the 2d array you mentioned in the above question. Please use functions to manage for null.

while ($myrow = pg_fetch_array($records)) {
      if ($myrow['id'] == 123) $yourow[] = $myrow['first_name'];
} 

print_r($yourow);
```